# what the way to recognise image in android ?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, neural-network, tensorflow, image-recognition

i was trying to find to recognise images using android application  (NOT detecting ) , i need my application to learn my camera about some shapes i draw it by my self then make code , that the camera will understand if its seeing image 1 , change to image 2 , i have searching for long time all i found some information about name of libraries :

```
tensor flow 
openCv
neruoph
```

i tried with opencv , but i understand its detect not recognise , please any one can help and give me more information , like what i should start or read , links to some tutorial for example it will be great ?

Comment: You should read more about image classifier. Someone asks the same thing in 
[link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3380/classification-of-object-from-a-videoimage-human-animals-otherscars-etc/?answer=3991#post-id-3991). This answer suggested [link](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/) to read which is a BoW based object classifier.

Answer (score 1):

I tried OpenCV and TensorFlow.

Here's a quick review for each:

- OpenCV is good but I would use it more for detecting colors and shapes in realtime.
- TensorFlow is also huge, I used the example they provided (TensorFlow for Peots) which is extremly simple but very powerful tool to recognize things based on images you trained to the system. Here are some links that are useful for what you want:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSKfRcEDGUs

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0